# background image does not change by java script

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a list set up in HTML as follows:

HTML:

```
<ul id="move_2">
 <li id="mv_txt_2" >Move Section Up</li>
</ul> 
<button onClick="position();">change the bg_image</button>
```

CSS:

```
#move_2 {
    height:20px;
    background:url(../images/mvup.fw.png) no-repeat;
    padding-left:30px;
    margin-top:15px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    list-style:none;}


#mv_txt_2{
    padding-left:5px;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size:14px;
    vertical-align:middle;}
```

But the following javascript does not change the background image:

```
function position(){
 document.getElementById('move_2').style.background='url(../images/mvdown.fw.png)';
}
```

I'd be grateful to receive any comments to solve this problem.

Comment: Are your css and js in seperate files from the html file?

Comment: It looks like its changing to the same image?

Comment: You should learn to use events outside of the HTML. inline event handling shouldn't be used past the basics of learning to use events

Comment: @ jbyrne2007 - javascript is in html file but I wrote css in an external file

Comment: @  Sterling Archer - I did not use internal CSS

Comment: You have to wrap the element ID in quotation marks, otherwise it's looking for a variable called `move_2` Also, it looks like you might want to fire the `position()` function via the button, currently it's tied to the "Move selection up" text.

Comment: @HNML event handling is the `onclick` attribute, not CSS. It's better practice (but more advanced JS) to abstract the JavaScript from your HTML.

Comment: @  Sterling Archer - You're right. I am studying but has only started JS for about a week!

Comment: @HNML no worries, but keep it in mind for the future :)

Comment: @  Sterling Archer - I think I have correted my mistakes if you look at the edits in my post. But still the background image does not change. I'd be happy to have your comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

### Demo on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uc78b1pc/)

#### HTML:

```
<ul id="move_2">
    <li id="mv_txt_2">Move Section Up</li>
</ul>
<button>change the bg_image</button>
```

#### CSS:

```
#move_2 {
    height:200px;
    background:url(http://istheapplestoredown.com/images/dashboardwidget.png) no-repeat;
    padding-left:30px;
    margin-top:15px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    list-style:none;
}
#mv_txt_2 {
    padding-left:5px;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size:14px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

#### JavaScript:

```
$('li').click(function position() {
    document.getElementById('move_2').style.background = 'url(http://istheapplestoredown.com/images/websitewidget.png) no-repeat';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think ../images works in CSS because your CSS is in a directory. When working with html you must use absolute path. Did you try :

```
 document.getElementById('move_2').style.background='url(images/mvdown.fw.png)';
```

And use "onclick" instead of onClick.

Comment: @ fathyb - Yes, I think it was the problem I had. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

1. You shouldn't use attributes width capital words.
2. You can use this by jquery:

html:

```
 onclick="..."
```

jquery:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#move_2").css("background" , "yourAddress");
 });
```